# Second bootstrap navbar has gap between menu bar and the menu content on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am currently using bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com) for the first time and I have a page with the main menu and then a secondary menu underneath.

I've got it mostly working but when viewed on mobile, and the menu button is pressed there's a gap between the menu bar and the menu content as shown in the screenshot below

[image: Menu screenshot]

I want to get rid of the gap so the menu content is directly underneath the nav bar (still showing the bottom border)

Below is the code for my second nav bar

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper" style="padding: 5px;">
        <div class="container" style="padding: 5px;">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-xs navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #E2DFE5; border: solid thin black; margin: 0;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#portalNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" style="margin-top: 0 !important;">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: black;"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: black;"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: black;"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="portalNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="background-color: #E2DFE5;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="height: 25px;">
                            <li><a href="/">Portal Dashboard</a></li>

                        </ul>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 3px;">
                            <li><a href="/administrator/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider general declaration for the styles:

```
* {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

This will tell: use 0 padding and 0 margin for all the elements on your web page.

That might solve the issue. Also, when debugging, it is a good trick to temporarily set

`border: solid black 1px;`

for both menus to see which one is causing the gap. 
I would add this line to both styles and depending on where the gap is coming from - troubleshooted.

Comment: Thanks I've given that a try, but no joy. I've put a border around it shows the border is just around the blue portion that comes down, I've tried putting margin 0 and padding 0 for the navbar and container but no you

Comment: Does it happen only on mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, only the panel shown in the screenshot shows on a mobile, on a desktop its just a standard horizontal navigation bar